# What does 'content: "\e61e"' mean in CSS?

Tags: fonts, icon, css

Wonder what `content:"\e61e"` is in the `.icon-trash:before` class' CSS. I know that they use a font to make icons but I don't know what "\e61e" is? Any explanation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a special set of unicode characters, that point to specific symbol within the font. If I had to guess, I'd say that the reason why they don't use letters from `a` to `z`, is that, if for example the font doesn't load correctly, you are left with something like this: `Download ⁠` ( or it might render as empty, I'm not exactly sure ) and not something like: `Download a`, because the browser would render it with another font instead.

Comment: So how they know unicode of  each font?

Comment: I don't understand where this question is coming from. Why would they need to know that? When they make a icon font, they are the ones who decide what unicode character they want to map their symbols to. If they want to map a `trash can` to `e61e`, then that's what they do and no other font has anything to say about it.

Answer (score 3):

`\e61e` is technically this character: [](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/58910/UTF-8-character) in UTF-8 encoding (the default encoding for CSS - this can be changed using [`@charset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset)). So that's the literal answer to your question.

But as [Joonas mentioned in the comments](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66038/content-e61e-what-is-mean-in-css3#comment99443_66038), a font can map a character like this to a symbol, in this case an icon, of their choosing. So in actuality, what you're seeing is likely different than this character - likely a trash can icon.

Since it's inside of a `::before` (two colons are used because it's a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) - one colon should be used for [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)), that allows it to be placed separately from the `.icon-trash` element itself, usually before or after the element. This is very common for icon fonts to do.

Comment: And since the character is well inside the Private User Area of Unicode, the *glyph* does not display anything useful if it doesn't also have the *font* applied to it. For any other font, you may see nothing, the regular 'not-available'  Missing Character for your current font, or - my favourite - any random character that just happens to be in this place.